# Failed to apply plugin 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, blockchain, corda

I cloned cordapp-template-java using the below link.
https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java.git
Branch - release-V4

**1) I executed gradle build/clean from IntelliJ gradle sidebar. It's failing with below error stack.**

Build file 'D:\blockchain\build.gradle' line: 60

Failed to apply plugin 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'.
Collection contains no element matching the predicate.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

**2) Executed gradle command with --stacktrace.**

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin 'net.corda.plugins.cordapp'

Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.